# Vector <int> input and output

Tags: c++, stl, vector, cin

I am stuck with simple vector input and output operations. The compiler returns error saying 'std::outof range'

Here is the code

```
int main()
{
int size;
cout <<"Enter size of vector\n";
cin>>size;
cout<<"Now to input the vector of size "<<size<<endl;
vector <int> trial;
for (size_t i=0;i<size;++i){
    int x;
    cout<<"write at position"<<trial.at(i)<<'t';
    cin>>x;
    trial.push_back(x);
    cout<<endl;
}
ostream_iterator<int> output(cout,"");
copy(trial.begin(),trial.end(),output);
}
```

I would appreciate a brief explanation of the internal workings of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the first iteration of this loop:

```
vector <int> trial;
for (size_t i=0;i<size;++i){
    int x;
    cout<<"write at position"<<trial.at(i)<<'t';
```

At the first iteration nothing has been pushed into the vector, so `trial.at(0)` isn't yet valid. The result will be an exception. Since you don't have a `try`/`catch` anywhere, that will end your program's execution.

It looks to me like you want `cout << "write at position " << i;` instead. `i` is the position; after it has been pushed onto the vector so it's valid, `vector.at(i)` will be the value at that position.

Answer (score 5):

You invoke `trial.at(i)` before `trial.push_back(x)`, accessing a not yet existing element. Since the element doesn't (yet) exist, `i` is an invalid index, and `at()` will throw a `std::out_of_range` exception when passed an invalid index. If an exception isn't caught, it will terminate the program. Presumably your platform's runtime library displays the exception that caused the program to be terminated.

I suppose what you actually want is this:

```
std::cout << "write at position " << i << '\t';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
trial.at(i)
```

You're accessing an element that doesn't exist.

You probably want `cout<<"write at position"<< i <<'t';` anyway.

Comment: I am simply trying to write into the vector, should i first initialize it at position [0] and then use cin to fill it ?

Comment: @AlterEgo why are you attempting to read the i'th element of the vector when you haven't inserted it yet?

Comment: @AlterEgo just put `cin>>x;
    trial.push_back(x);` before you access the element.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
cout<<"write at position"<<trial.at(i)<<'t';
```

You call this before you have set the size of the vector.  I'm not really sure what that line is trying to accomplish anyway.  If you're trying to print the in memory position (address) that won't do it, if you're trying to print what was already there then it would work if it had already been allocated.  Using `vector::push_back()` means that you don't need to preallocate though.

You can fix this by resizing the `vector` and accessing the elements directly like this:

```
trial.resize(size);
// loop
// vector.push_back(x) -- now becomes
vector[i] = x;
```

Or, you can simply remove the printing of the position and use `push_back()` as you are now.

Since it seems you're investigating how to use `vector` I would suggest trying to gain an understanding of how the `push_back()` and `resize()` methods differ, and have also have a look at the `vector::reserve()` function.